# Can I directly connect microphone to speaker of two SIM800Ls

Tags: audio, differential, gsm, gprs

There are two [SimCom SIM800L](https://img.filipeflop.com/files/download/Datasheet_SIM800L.pdf) quad-band GSM/GPRS modules. I would like to make some kind of call relay, such that SIM #1 accepts incoming call, then SIM #2 executes outgoing call, and once both connections are established, the person who called SIM #1 should be able to hear and talk to the person to whom SIM #2 called.

Can I directly connect SIM #1 and SIM #2 sound outputs and inputs?

Assuming it is possible, should the pins be connected like this?

```
SIM1 MICP <-> SIM2 SPCP 
SIM1 MICN <-> SIM2 SPCN
SIM1 SPCP <-> SIM2 MICP 
SIM1 SPCN <-> SIM2 MICN
```

Comment: The datasheet says the microphone port has a bias voltage, so I would suggest adding capacitors in between to block the bias voltage. After that, I would just test it and see if the volume is too loud and if there is clipping. Then I would either adjust the volume or add voltage dividers if the volume doesn't go low enough.

Comment: @user253751 Should there be one capacitor per line, that is four in total, or should there be only two in between positive terminals? 

What should be the capacitance, around 1mkF I guess?